# Expected 'float *' but argument is of type 'float' при передаче параметров в функцию

Tags: c

Собственно, у меня компилятор выдает ошибку

> expected 'float *' but argument is of
> type 'float'

Я знаю, что неправильно заношу данные в функцию, и вообще у меня все функции плохо взаимодействуют, но не знаю, как это исправить.
Можно записать все в мэйн, я так делаю уже 2 месяца, но нужно исправляться.

```
#include <stdio.h>
define MAX 100

int getk (float k1[], int degree)
{
    int i;
    int c;
    printf("enter k");
    for (i=0; i<=(degree); i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &k1[i]);
    }
    return 1;
}

int deriv_k(float k1[], float k2[], int degree)
{
    int i;
   for(i=0; i<=(degree-1); i++)
   {
        k2[i]=(degree-i)*k1[i];
   }
return 1;
}

int residue(float S[], float Q[], int degree)
{   int i,j;
    float P[MAX];
    for (int i=0;i<=(degree-2);i++) S[i]=0;

  for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
  {
    S[i]=P[i]/Q[0];
    for(int j=0;j<=(degree-2);j++)
      P[i+j]-=S[i]*Q[j];
  }
}

void main(void)
{
    float k1[MAX];
    float k2[MAX];
    float k3[MAX];
    float res[MAX];
    int n;
    printf("enter degree");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    getk(k1[MAX], n);
    deriv_k(k1[MAX], k2[MAX], n);
    deriv_k(k2[MAX], k3[MAX], (n-1));
    residue(k1[MAX], k3[MAX], n);
}
```

П.С. Модераторам:
я не понял, как форматировать текст.

Comment: @VanPersie, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: @VanPersie, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3):

Основная ошибка в том, что ваши функции принимают на вход массивы float, тогда как вы отправляете им просто float (собственно, об этом вам любезно подсказывает компилятор) Причем, это даже не какое-то значение, а неизвестно что - элементы массивов под индексом MAX у вас явно не инициализированы и содержат некий мусор. То есть вместо

```
getk(k1[MAX], n);
```

вам следует написать

```
getk(k1, n);
```

И так далее для остальных функций. Следует также отметить, что если ваша функция не должна ничего возвращать, то стоит объявить ей в качестве возвращаемого значения void, а не писать каждый раз return 1 (либо возвращать какое-то действительно полезное значение).